# Why is my XML schema not validating?

Tags: java, xml, soap, polymorphism

I have the following Java classes:

```
public class input{

@XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.com/TopLevel")
public TopLevel TopLevel;
}
```

and

```
public class TopLevel{
    private String attribute;

    public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }
}
```

and

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(namespace="http://org.classes.SubClass", name="SubClass")
public class SubClass extends TopLevel {
    private String attribute2;

    public String getAttribute2() {
        return attribute2;
    }

    public void setAttribute2(String attribute2) {
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
    }
}
```

After deploying the classes I want to make a SOAP request and be able to morph TopLevel to SubClass in the XML. My request looks as such:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
... xmlns:top1="http://www.example.com/TopLevel" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <top:TopSubClass_TestRequest>
         <par:input>
            <input>
               <top1:toplevel xsi:type="ns5:subclass" xmlns:ns5="http://org.classes.SubClass">
                  <attribute2>test</attribute2>
               </top1:toplevel>
            </input>
         </par:input>
      </top:TopSubClass_TestRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I am expecting is that SubClass will be mapped to TopLevel and I would be able to use `attribute2` yet for some reason this won't validate. Nevermind the namespaces in the request that don't seem to be defined. I skipped them to make the request readable more easily. The validation trouble occurs at the line:

`<top1:toplevel xsi:type="ns5:subclass" xmlns:ns5="http://org.classes.SubClass">`

Saying:

`Invalid xsi:type qname: 'subclass' in element Input`

Can anyone point me at what I am doing wrong? According to all examples I found this is supposed to be the way to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.
I am using IBM ODM and even though all my classes had namespaces defined ODM doesn't import the namespace into the WSDL unless the objects are defined in the input object.

Thus I needed to add:

```
@XmlType(namespace = "Some namespace")
public class Input() {
    public TopLevel topLevel;
    public SubClass subClass;
}
```

and annotate TopLevel and SubClass with the `@XmlType` annotation.